# 'Pyqt5' and 'multiprocessing' does not draw graph

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pyqt5

I want to learn how to work with the 'multiprocessing' module.
Tried using in 'pyqt5'. Processes are started, but the graph is not drawn.
I know that 'pyqt' has its own classes for threads and processes.
But I want to use 'multiprocessing'.

```
import numpy as np
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtChart
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from multiprocessing import Process
import time


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self._chart_view = QtChart.QChartView()
        self.chart = QtChart.QChart()
        central_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)
        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(central_widget)
        lay.addWidget(self._chart_view)
        procs = []
        k = 0
        for i in range(0, 3):
            k+=1
            proc = Process(target=self.print_func, args=(i,))
            procs.append(proc)
            print('first cycle before', procs[i].is_alive())
            proc.start()
            print('first cycle after', procs[i].is_alive())

        for proc in procs:
            proc.join()

    def print_func(self, cou):
        print(cou)
        time.sleep(3)
        U1 = np.random.random(500)
        U2 = np.random.random(500)
        scatterU = QtChart.QScatterSeries()
        if cou == 1:
            scatterU.setColor(Qt.darkGreen)
        if cou == 2:
            scatterU.setColor(Qt.darkBlue)
        if cou == 3:
            scatterU.setColor(Qt.red)
        scatterU.setMarkerSize(10.0)
        for i in range(0, 500):
            scatterU.append(U1[i], U2[i])

        self.chart.addSeries(scatterU)
        self.chart.createDefaultAxes()
        self._chart_view.setChart(self.chart)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: You can't, not like this, not easily, and not painlessly. The problem is not even with PyQt (which, remember, is a python *wrapper* around Qt, which is written in C++), nor that "Qt has its own classes for threads and processes", but the fact that UI elements are ***not*** thread safe: trying to access the UI from an external thread is not only unsupported (best case scenario, you get drawing artifact or no drawing at all) but it can also cause crashes. To avoid that, the only option is to use signals, but that won't help your case as they only work with threads, since they shared memory.

Comment: What you're trying to do is ***never*** going to work. You cannot create Qt objects in child processes and use them directly in the main process. And there is no simple way to transfer such complex structures between processes whilst preserving state. Multiprocessing has its uses, but it's not the magic bullet you imagine it to be. If you want to improve performance, move the *non-GUI* calculations to a worker thread and send updates back to the main thread via signals. (NB: Qt does not support gui-related operations of any kind outside the main thread).

Comment: Processes, instead, do ***not*** share memory, so you cannot even directly communicate with them using signals. The only (difficult) available option is to use a complex system that maps messages between the multiprocess into signals (see https://elsampsa.github.io/valkka-examples/_build/html/qt_notes.html#python-multiprocessing ) but I really won't suggest that, as it requires a *lot* of experience and knowledge on how both Qt and multiprocessing works. For general uses, QThreads are the simplest and *safest* way to achieve "parallel" processing (even if it's not exactly parallelism).

Comment: Thanks! Very informative. The GIL states that only one thread can run at a time. 
In my understanding, the next thread will wait for the other to complete to start. 
Or is it not entirely true?

Comment: @inquirer no, that "running" doesn't mean that the thread has to be completed. The GIL is released whenever the currently running thread allows it (for instance, by using a very short `time.sleep()`). While it's not as optimal as actual multiprocessing, it's usually fine for most scenarios.